# SQL query to find unengaged subscriber confusion

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I want to exclude subscribers who have not ‘opened’ or ‘clicked’ email in last 6 months.
I have the below sql query. Is this SQL query correct?
Does the final results of this sql query results have only email-addresses that have not engaged?

```
select  email from All_Active_Subscribers
where email not in (
    select EmailAddress from _Subscribers s
    left join _Click c on c.subscriberId = s.subscriberId and c.EventDate > dateadd(dd,-180,getdate())
    left join _Open o on o.subscriberId = s.subscriberId and o.EventDate > dateadd(dd,-180,getdate())
    and c.subscriberId is not null or o.subscriberId is not null
    ) 
group by email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```sql
select
email 
from All_Active_Subscribers
where not exists (
  select top 1 c.*
  from _Click c 
  where c.subscriberId = s.subscriberId
)
and not exists (
  select top 1 o.*
  from _Open o
  where o.subscriberId = s.subscriberId
)
```

The reason I would not use joins... Well, it's a one-to-many situation where you don't want multiple matches.  The "not exists" is a better option because you don't have to group or aggregate just to return a single subscriber.

The data views are limited to 6 months worth of data, so no need to include any date criteria.

If you did need to limit it by date (e.g in the last 60 days), I'd do the date math like this -- which I've found to be the most performant method:

```sql
select
email 
from All_Active_Subscribers
where not exists (
  select top 1 c.*
  from _Click c 
  where c.subscriberId = s.subscriberId
  and c.eventDate >= convert(date,getDate()-60)
)
and not exists (
  select top 1 o.*
  from _Open o
  where o.subscriberId = s.subscriberId
  and o.eventDate >= convert(date,getDate()-60)
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Because we are using “All_Active_Subscribers” DE and then removing  records that have  unengaged using “where not exists” query . 
 As a result will the Targeted DE  has customers who have  unengaged or engaged  ?

Comment: The results of the first query would give you subscribers who have not opened or clicked in the last 6 months -- so unengaged.

Comment: thank you for your reply